# How to have a form inside a table consisting a while loop

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, bootstrap-4

I want to include a form inside a table that consists of a while loop. The submit button of the code i have mentioned below does not work. Also i tried putting the form tag before the table tag, then all the figures are getting reflected in the get url at one go.

```
    <table class="table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col"> KPI ID</th>
      <th scope="col">KPI Name</th>
      <th scope="col">Weightage</th>
      <th scope="col">Rating</th>


    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <?php

  $connect = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "ITP_HR"); 
  $id = $_GET['id']; 
  $sql = "SELECT kpi_id,kpi_name,rating,Weight,Fin_Rating FROM kpi where Emp_ID =$id"; 
  $result=mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
//   var_dump($result);
  while($row =  mysqli_fetch_array($result) ){

    $kpi_idp = $row['kpi_id'];
    $kpi_namep =$row['kpi_name'];
    $Weight = $row['Weight'];
    $Fin_Rating =$row['Fin_Rating'];
   ?>


    <tr> 
    <form action="update_ftask.php" method="GET">
    <td scope="row"><?=$kpi_idp?><input type="hidden" name="<?=$kpi_idp?>"></td>
    <td scope="row"><?=$kpi_namep?></td>
    <td scope="row"><?=$Weight?></td> 
    <td scope="row"><input type="number" name="<?=$Fin_Rating?>"></td>
    <td scope="row"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button></td>

    </form>     

    </tr>

    </tbody>
  <?php
    // $i++;
  }
  ?> 

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: To be valid HTML the form must either wholly contain the table or be wholly contained within a table-cell ( td ) element. As your HTML is above now it is not valid

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow @Natasha. I hope you get a quick response to yr question. If its possible, help people by abstracting your "production" code into a similar sample. Which makes it easier to read and comprehend.

Answer (score 2):

Correct, you can't enclose `td` or `tr` in `<form>`. But you can create `form` inside a `td`.

For example:

```
<tr> 
    <td scope="row"><?=$kpi_idp?></td>
    <td scope="row"><?=$kpi_namep?></td>
    <td scope="row"><?=$Weight?></td> 
    <td scope="row">
        <form action="update_ftask.php" method="GET">
            <input type="hidden" name="<?=$kpi_idp?>">
            <input type="number" name="<?=$Fin_Rating?>">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </form>     
    </td>
</tr>
```

Another solution is to use javascript magic and listen to `<form>` `submit` event. On this event you collect required data (from `input`s of a related `tr`) and send to server.